# How to set a percentage threshold \delta such that the portion of body text in a page cannot be in (0, \delta) (but 0 is fine)?

Tags: floats, positioning

Suppose you have figures A, B, C, D, E, F that take up 10%, 50%, 30%, 40%, 50%, 60% of the page respectively. I want that placement to be

...after the body text finishes a page

[page with 90% ABC and 10% blank]

[page with 90% DE and 10% blank]

[page with 60% F and 40% continued body text]

However, if I just experiment with combinations of `!`,`h`,`p` and the use of `afterpage` and `clearpage`, I will get one of the followings:

0. Using `h`:
   You will get pages with A+B+body, C+body, D+body, E+body, F+body. The figures cut into way too much body text afterwards.
1. Using `!h`:

[page with 90% ABC and 10% body text]

[page with 90% DE and 10% body text]

[page with 60% F and 40% body text]

Squeezing the body in the 10% space makes it very fragmented and hard to follow.

2. Using `!ph` or `ph` or `p` or `!p`:
   The figures simply go to the end of the file.
3. Using some combination of `afterpage`, `clearpage`:
   I can achieve this:

...after the body text finishes a page

[page with 90% ABC and 10% blank]

[page with 90% DE and 10% blank]

[page with 60% F and 40% blank]

but the 40% white space is too much.

**In summary,** I look for a way that still respects the minimal portion of body text, but allows the portion to be zero in order for the floats to finish sooner. On the other hand, one can force this "zero" by using `p` and `clearpage`, but it will have a side effect of creating a white space that is too large.

**Edit:**
To explain the text placement, let's say the numbers 1,2,3,... refer to body text that takes up 10% of the space, then the intended placement is as follows. Also, say the section consists of body text 1,2,...,15 (one and a half page on its own) and figures A,...,F that best fit between 6 and 7.

## Intended:

1

2

...

6 //receives the request of lots of figures, put them as soon as the page ends

7

...

10

---

A

B

C

(10% blank)

---

D

E

(10% blank)

---

F

11

12

13

14

---

15

16 //next section starts

...(continue)

---

If I just use `h` with a minimal text proportion 25%, the placement will be something like

## Want to avoid:

1

2

...

6

A //10%

7

8

9

---

B //50%

10

...

14

---

C // 30%

D // 40%

15

16 // next section starts here

17

---

E // 50%

18

...

22

---

F // 60%

23

24

25

26...(continues)

---

As we see, it would interfere with way too much text in the next section.

Comment: using `!` is an explicit instruction to ignore the constraints on the proportion of a page given to figures

Comment: your question is not very clear, you appear to want all the figures after the text, if you place them after the text  in the source you would get what you want, I suspect.

Comment: why are you using `\clearpage` if you do not want to force white space, what happens if you use no option, and no \clearpage  ?

Comment: 1. With or without `!`, my current understanding is that it will still try to fill a page, except that with `!`, the text proportion is allowed to be very low. 2. I want the figures to start at the next page, but not way after. I am going to edit to make this clearer. 3. The reason for \clearpage is a workaround of situation (2): using anything involving `p`, the figures end up at the end of the entire file (though I don't know why), but if I use `clearpage' somewhere, then the figures will come in right there. However, it causes the situation (3).